# AS3 Button Calls MC inside Two Level Loaded External SWF

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a button on parent to call mc_target into two levels hierarchy of loaded swf. Any idea to solve that is greatly appreciated.

Simply it goes as bellow:

In parent I load external swf1 using below class

```
var swfLoader: Loader = new Loader();
var swfFile: URLRequest = new URLRequest(".swf1");
var context: LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.allowCodeImport = true;
//
swfLoader.load(swfFile, context);
addChild(swfLoader);
//
swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoadedHandler);
function swfLoadedHandler(e: Event): void {
    var SWFMC: MovieClip = MovieClip(swfLoader.content);
    //
    SWFMC.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Then inside swf1 I also load external swf2 with the above code using var **SWFMC2**. Everthing done as well, but The problem is my button cannot calls mc_target inside swf2 directly. Below is my code in parent to call mc_target.

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
SWFMC1.SWFMC2.mc_target.visible = true;
}
```

**SWFMC** is var to convert the external swf1 and swf2 to MovieClip to get communicate each other through allowCodeImport class. And now I would like my button in parent timeline make mc_target inside swf2 visible instantly.

Please help

Thank's

Comment: Please **edit** the question and elaborate on the details. The hierarchy of your setup is not clear, thus it is not clear what are you trying to achieve and why doesn't it work.

Comment: Thank for your attention, Organis. My problem clearly like the above I retype. Please advise any solution

Comment: Btw, much apologize for my bad english. May you could advise too 

Comment: Ok, problems I can see so far: 1) **Event.COMPETE** fires when all bytes are loaded. Use **Event.INIT** instead, it occurs later, when the loaded content is actually initialized. 2) **SWFMC** is a local variable inside a function. It does not exist for any code outside of the function. You should declare the variable outside of the function.

Comment: Using **allowCodeImport** it can targeting parent timeline outside the SWFMC where swf loaded, simply using **parent** callback. But unfortunately it doesn't targeting the main timeline of outsider onto top level. I think it seems need to declare a variable to convert the **swfloader** as MovieClip which can bypass easily. However I have to try your option first

Comment: The hierarchy of the loaded content is the following: main swf > **Loader** instance > main timeline of the loaded swf. That's why you cannot target the main timeline with a single **parent**.

Comment: Right. I try make false mc as trigger inside swf1 to affects to swf2 but failed too. The tigger is make false mc then meke it invisible first. I just try using **if** condition.